# SQL - Can't move data from one column in one table to another column in another table

Tags: mysql

Good day to all - I am a novice in SQL and have reviewed potential solutions here to this problem. The first approach of using Insert Into commands do not work, period. It creates double rows and NULLS.

I have read and tried solutions posted here using Update-Join syntax. Can't see to get it right, maybe I don't need a WHERE condition, maybe I do, etc.

Here are the two tables. I want to take data from IPTEST table, IP column and insert it into the POSTALTEST table, IP column:

```
 IPTEST TABLE
+---------------+
| IP            |
+---------------+
| 65.4.166.241  |
| 65.49.188.24  |
| 65.12.231.173 |
| 65.30.224.18  |
| 65.83.140.96  |
+---------------+

POSTALTEST TABLE
+-------+------+-----------+------+
| zip   | zip4 | ailmentID | IP   |
+-------+------+-----------+------+
| 15227 | 3709 |        26 | NULL |
| 15227 | 3724 |        29 | NULL |
| 15227 | 3736 |        22 | NULL |
| 15227 | 3737 |        22 | NULL |
| 15227 | 3737 |        26 | NULL |
+-------+------+-----------+------+
```

I would be so grateful if someone can help, went to links of "learn about join" already so please someone spare me the humiliation of posting that and help me with the syntax :D

Kind Regards,

Jason

Comment: Adding the query to this question would help, in case something in the query is wrong and casing undesired behavior.

Comment: Sorry tables didn't paste cleanly.

Comment: There's no relationship between the two tables.  How do you know which IP goes with which postaltest record?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? You also have to [edit] your question and add the queries that are not working including any error message (formatted text please [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557))

Comment: I am using INNODB.

Comment: Here is the syntax I tried and error:

Comment: mysql> update postaltest set postaltest.IP = (select IP from iptest where postaltest.IP = iptest.IP) update postaltest, iptest set postaltest.IP = iptest.IP where postaltest.IP = iptest.IP;
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'update postaltest, iptest set postaltest.IP = iptest.IP where postaltest.IP = ip' at line 1

Answer (score 0):

**If you are using SQL SERVER:**

I suggest you to create one more column which will be the primary key in first table and to add FOREIGN CONSTRAINT to create relationship between between the first and second table

```
     IPTEST TABLE   
   +---------------++---------------+
   |   IP_ID        |     IP        |
   +---------------++---------------+
   | 1             || 65.4.166.241  |
   | 2             || 65.49.188.24  |
   | 3             || 65.12.231.173 |
   | 4             || 65.30.224.18  |
   | 5             || 65.83.140.96  |
   +---------------++---------------+

-- add primary key

ALTER TABLE IPTEST ADD PRIMARY KEY (IP_ID)

    POSTALTEST TABLE
  +-------+------+-----------+------+
  | zip   | zip4 | ailmentID | IP   |
  +-------+------+-----------+------+
  | 15227 | 3709 |        26 | 1    |
  | 15227 | 3724 |        29 | 2    |
  | 15227 | 3736 |        22 | 3    |
  | 15227 | 3737 |        22 | 4    |
  | 15227 | 3737 |        26 | 5    |
  +-------+------+-----------+------+

-- add FOREIGN CONSTRAINT to create relationship

  ALTER TABLE POSTALTEST 
  ADD CONSTRAINT FK_X FOREIGN KEY (IP)
  REFERENCES IPTEST (IP_ID);

-- inner join
 SELECT ip_1.*,pt.*
 FROM IPTEST  as ip_1
 INNER JOIN POSTALTEST as pt on ip_1 = pt.IP
```

If you just wanna to know how to use insert select than u can use:

```
  INSERT INTO POSTALTEST (IP)
  SELECT IP
  FROM IPTEST
```

Comment: Dejan thanks for the post. On first trying to alter the IPTEST table to add primary key got this error:

Comment: mysql> ALTER TABLE iptest ADD PRIMARY KEY (IP_ID);
ERROR 1072 (42000): Key column 'IP_ID' doesn't exist in table

Comment: @user3244822 you need to create IP_ID column first